# The program is not taking any input. After very first input it closes automatically

Tags: c++

I'm trying to access the structure via pointers. I think the problem is in line 13. Can anyone tell me whats the problem actually is and how to solve it?

```
    #include <iostream>
struct friends {
    std::string name;
    std::string lastName;
    int age{};
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int numberOfFriends{0};
    cout << "Please enter the number of the friends: ";
    cin >> numberOfFriends;
    friends *dost[numberOfFriends];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFriends; ++i) {
        cout << "Please enter the name of " << i + 1 << " friend: ";
        cin>>(dost[i]->name);
        cout << "Please enter the last name of " << i + 1 << " friend: ";
        cin >> dost[i]->lastName;
        cout << "Please enter the age of " << i + 1 << " friend: ";
        cin >> dost[i]->age;
    }
    cout << "You entered following data. Please have a look: " << endl;
    cout << "****************************************************" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFriends; ++j) {
        cout << "Friend     :" << j + 1 << endl;
        cout << "Name       :" << dost[j]->name << endl;
        cout << "Last Name  :" << dost[j]->name << endl;
        cout << "Full Name  :" << dost[j]->name << " " << dost[j]->lastName << endl;
        cout << "Age        :" << dost[j]->age << endl;
        cout << "****************************************************" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `friends *dost[numberOfFriends];` is not valid C++.

Comment: `dost[i]->name` dereferences an uninitialized pointer (`dost[0]`).

Comment: @melpomene than what is friends *dost[numberOfFriends]; doing. It is not making it of type friend?

Comment: its an array of pointers not an array of objects. pointers just point somewhere, if you dont create objects then there are none. If you want objects then use objects not pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed down to

```
friends *dost[numberOfFriends];
```

You don't allocate any memory for the pointer, and variable length arrays are not portable either.

A replacement is

```
std::vector<friends> dost(numberOfFriends);
```

although you will need to replace `dost[i]->` with `dost[i].` although I'd be inclined to use `dost.at(i).` as this makes a run-time bounds check on the index.

Comment: can you do it via array? I mean without vector

Comment: Yes I could, but that would be a *vastly* inferior solution.

Comment: @GauravThakur Why should one do that without using `std::vector`, that doesn't make much sense at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I am new to C++ that's why.

Comment: @GauravThakur - Even more reason to favor `std::vector`, it will give you far less WTF moments than raw c-style arrays while you are learning.

Comment: @GauravThakur [It's all well documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). _"Actually I am new to C++ that's why."_ is just a poor excuse to ask such a very low quality quesiton at Stack Overflow IMO.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks!